# How do i call .phtml block at specfic page in magento?

Tags: magento

How do i use test.phtml at test page i used following code but it didnt work

```
{{block type='core/template' name='Test' template='goodtest/test.phtml'}}
```

But it didnt show anything at the page. So did i missed anything? do i need to put some code in other files, like page.xml or local.xml.

Thanks

Comment: What's the magento relative path to your template?

Answer (score 15):

your code looks good for to add in CMS page. 
if you want to add .phtml file in a .phtml file then you can use like this.
you don't need to add anything in xml file

```
    <?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
First create a page in CMS pages in admin panel and add the following code to the content of the CMS page. It will call the content of this page in the main content area.

```
{{block type='page/html' template='page/html/demo.phtml'}}
```