# want to call one phtml file in another phtml file using anchor tag

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink

I'm using Magento.

I want display and call one `phtml` file as a link in another `phtml` file…

I have the `new.phtml` file on the home page. On that I put one link CHECK ALL which display all new products as category page.. It looks like category page. For that I create another `phtml` file named `newproductpage.phtml` which has same code of `new.phtml`. Now I try to call this `newproductpage.phtml` file @homepage as CHECK ALL link for that I write this code....

```php
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUr('newproductpage.phtml')?>">CHECK ALL</a>
```

But its not working....

thnx..

Comment: Check this link here = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263663/magento-call-cms-page-through-anchor-tag-from-phtml-file

Answer (score 16):

you call newproductpage.phtml in any phtml file using below code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/newproductpage.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the below code for rendering your phtml file in another phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('templatefolderpath/filename.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

For more refinement of your code, you can use the block name and block file name instead of core/template because core/template use the core resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can not call directly one phtml file to another phtml file.

But there are two way to call your phtml file either create one controller and create one action and call action from your anchor tag or create one cms page which call your phtml file.

if you create one module, so in your layout file something you can write

```
<modulename_controllername_controlleraction>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" template="custom/newproductpage.phtml" />
    </reference>
</module_controllername_controlleraction>
```

Or you can directly put this code in your cms page content area

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="custom/newproductpage.phtml"}}
```

and in anchor tag give cms page link.

Comment: if i want to display addnewproduct.phtml in new.phtml as link...what to do?

Comment: i want to say that in the new.phtml file i give anchor tag named CHECK ALL and clicking on that newproductpage.phtml file will open..i am confusing with this. And ya.. new.phtml has no XMl file. new.phtml file call as block in the homepage.

Comment: Just add your cms page link to your anchor category link in check all and in cms page put this code `{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="custom/newproductpage.phtml"}}`

Comment: Bro, i dont want to call this block on home page...i already put the block of New.phtml and new.phtml = newproductpage.phtml, both have same feature to see new products. difference is that new.phtml is used as a one block on homepage with other blocks with slider. while newproductpage.phtml is a whole page looks like a category page with left sidebar which shows shop by,compare products,community poll,populartag etc and main has all new products... so can u give me any suggestion for this...!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

you can also check the link.

[Display .phtml page in another .phtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382959/display-phtml-page-in-another-phtml-page)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you and I want to do precisely the same thing.  I'm creating a modal from bootstrap and I need to call in a partial using the href attr.

So far, I think this might be possible by creating a page in the CMS and then using something like this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("page-name-in-CMS") ?>">Home</a></li>
```

But honestly, I'm just starting out with Magento and know very little.

Comment: thnx bro..we can create the same code cms page and call it using anchor...!!

Comment: Does that mean my answer helped you resolve your problem?  If so, please vote my answer up and select it! :)

Answer (score -9):

you can use iframe for same and load this another page content using AJAX call

Comment: iframe and ajax will make the things more complicated, instead directly define the block and template file using this code. <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/newproductpage.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>