# Display .phtml page in another .phtml page

Tags: php, magento, catalog

I have created a `new.phtml` page in `catalog/product/new.phtml`.
which contain `new/latest products`.
i have another `.phtml` page [`product_slider.phtml`]. i want to add `new.phtml` into `product_slider.phtml`
is this possibale.?? how to use.. any idea.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

After Trying the code i got the solution.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

To Display .phtml page in another .phtml page. you can use:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path after template dir/filename.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/product_slider.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

You have to make sure block type , rather then `core/template`